# Multi-Column IN and INDEX in MySQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause, where-in

I have a table like this in MySQL. (version is 5.5)

```
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field            | Type          | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| A                | varchar(50)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                |                             |
| B                | varchar(50)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                |                             |
                                               :
```

But index for WHERE (multi-column) IN does not work.

If number of the set after 'IN' is only one, index works.

```
explain SELECT * FROM table  WHERE (A, B) IN(('1', '2')) ;
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table             | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table             | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 304     | const,const |    1 |       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------+
```

But number of the set after 'IN' is more than two, index does not work.

```
explain SELECT * FROM table WHERE (A, B) IN(('1', '2'), ('3', '4'));
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table             | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 857897 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

Why index does not work?

**[UPDATE]**
If I changed query like below, Index works.

```
explain SELECT * FROM tabe  WHERE (A='1' AND B='2') or (A='3' AND B='4');
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table             | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 304     | NULL |    2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

But I'd rather like to use IN clause because AND/OR query is very long.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql not using an index on where in with two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451533/mysql-not-using-an-index-on-where-in-with-two-columns)

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve);

Comment: Thanks for reply. I realized MySQL 5.5 does not suport multi-column where in index. I'll check whether I can change my query to use AND/OR clause or have to examine another solution.

Comment: Use the update query. As queries fo it's not "very long", it's trivially small. If you are actually interested in a particular kind of test with particular tables where you (think) you want IN rather than AND/OR ask a new question giving the important details asking about best query form(s).